# iterate concatenations over pandas DataFrame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, concatenation

Good morning to all,
I have several dataframes

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':['a','b','c','d']})
b=pd.DataFrame({'a':[5,6,7,8], 'b':['e','f','g','h']})
...
z=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,1], 'b':['z','u','r','f']})

yyy=pd.DataFrame({'a':[13,14,15,16], 'b':['o','p','q','r']})
```

I need to concatenate them with another one using a loop so I don't have to write n times the same operation

```
for df in (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,z):
    df=pd.concat((df,y),axis=0)
```

If I use this code, I have no changes, and a new dataFrame called df with the last concatenation made inside the loop

```
df
    a  b
0   1  z
1   1  u
2   1  r
3   1  f
0  13  o
1  14  p
2  15  q
3  16  r
```

whereas the a,b,c... dataframes remain unchanged...
thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

You can merge more than one dataframes using :

```
frames = [df1, df2, df3] # in your case df1->a df2->b ...
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It would be a solution if I had to concatenate all the dfs, but what I want is something like:
a+yyy
b+yyy
c+yyy 
etc